# Wordpress Database Migration + MySQL 5.6 syntax error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, syntax-error, database-migration, mysql-5.6

Trying to search and replace URLs in a Wordpress database (MySQL 5.6). Easily found a few sites with the commands to do it, but keep getting a syntax error (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''http://oldurl''http://newurl') FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'home' OR o' at line 1).

Checked smart quotes, (and yes, did not use those placeholders), but I can't figure out why this version of MySQL is flagging the syntax.

Any eyes greatly appreciated.

-D

EDIT commands (ob. not OLD_URL and NEW_URL being used):

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'OLD_URL', 'NEW_URL') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

Comment: You should post the command that you're running.

Comment: It's thanks to the version: running the command on a higher MySQL db works just fine. Workaround for now is to create DB in higher version, run command, export and upload at lower version.